# bitbucket rest api to get the list of pull requests (OPEN) created from source (fromRef) branch to target branch (fromRef)

Tags: git, rest, bitbucket

I am trying to get the list of pull requests which created from source branch to target branch using the bitbucket rest api.

I have referred [this](https://docs.atlassian.com/DAC/rest/stash/3.11.6/stash-rest.html#idp3175008) link -  and I got `(/REST/API/1.0/PROJECTS/{PROJECTKEY}/REPOS/{REPOSITORYSLUG}/PULL-REQUESTS?AT)` "at" can do this but it is able to get the pull requests based on target branch only.

I want to get the pull requests based on both source and target branches. Please help me to get the rest api for it if available else suggest me any git command that can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you provided, as well as my limited experience with the BitBucket API, I believe you can get the pull requests where the branch/ref specified in the `at` parameter is the source by setting the `direction` parameter to `outgoing`.

So your relative URL would look like this: `REST/API/1.0/PROJECTS/{PROJECTKEY}/REPOS/{REPOSITORYSLUG}/PULL-REQUESTS?AT={refId}&direction=outgoing`

As an aside, if you are indeed using BitBucket and not Stash (previous incarnation/name), you will want to check the [REST documentation for the latest version of BitBucket](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/latest/bitbucket-rest.htm), or whichever version you are using, in case there are any disparities. This endpoint's definition has not changed, so no worries there.